# How to add UISegmentControl to CPTGraphHostingView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot

How to add a `UISegmentControl` to `CPGraphHostingView`? When I try to add `UISegmentControl` normally, It is covered by the `CPGraphHostingView`.

Comment: can you explain what is you requirement to put UISegment control to CPGraphHostingView?

Comment: i want a uisegement to show graph of 3 month, 1year etc data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try something like `[graphHostingView bringSubviewToFront:segmentedControl]`?

Comment: Also try `segmentedControl.layer.zPosition = 1`.

Comment: now it is displaying but i had put segmentcontrol down. it is displaying up and i can't press the segmentcontrol

Comment: Have a look at the `momentary` and `selectedSegmentIndex` properties: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't add subviews to a `CPTGraphHostingView`. Instead, make it and the `UISegmentControl` siblings with a common parent view.